# time complexity of the composite function in terms of n

Tags: runtime, scheme, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Assuming n is a positive integer, the composite function performs as follows:

```
(define (composite? n)
  (define (iter i)
    (cond ((= i n) #f)
          ((= (remainder n i) 0) #t)
          (else (iter (+ i 1)))))
  (iter 2))
```

It seems to me that the time complexity (with a tight bound) here is O(n) or rather big theta(n). I am just eyeballing it right now. Because we are adding 1 to the argument of iter every time we loop through, it seems to be O(n). Is there a better explanation?

Comment: You got it.  You increase by 1 each recursive call up to a maximum of `n`, and then stop.  If you assume that the divide operation is constant-time, then you do O(1) work each loop for a total of O(n).  It's only an upper bound though, because some inputs stop right away.  If `= n 800`, for example, you stop on the first loop where `(remainder n i)` is 0.

Comment: Right, if `n` is prime, the recursion goes all the way to `n`, `n-1` steps. But if `n` is composite, it takes at most `sqrt(n)` steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function as written is O(n). But if you change the test (= i n) to (< n (* i i)) the time complexity drops to O(sqrt(n)), which is a considerable improvement; if n is a million, the time complexity drops from a million to a thousand. That test works because if n = pq, one of p and q must be less than the square root of n while the other is greater than the square root of n; thus, if no factor is found less than the square root of n, n cannot be composite. Newacct's answer correctly suggests that the cost of the arithmetic matters if n is large, but the cost of the arithmetic is log log n, not log n as newacct suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Different people will give you different answers depending on what they assume and what they factor into the problem.

It is O(n) assuming that the equality and remainder operations you do inside each loop are O(1). It is true that the processor does these in O(1), but that only works for fixed-precision numbers. Since we are talking about asymptotic complexity, and since "asymptotic", by definition, deals with what happens when things grow without bound, we need to consider numbers that are arbitrarily big. (If the numbers in your problem were bounded, then the running time of the algorithm would also be bounded, and thus the entire algorithm would be technically O(1), obviously not what you want.)

For arbitrary-precision numbers, I would say that equality and remainder in general take time proportional to the size of the number, which is log n. (Unless you can optimize that away in amortized analysis somehow) So, if we consider that, the algorithm would be O(n log n). Some might consider this to be nitpicky